# Rmagick installed but I can't enable it in redmine

Tags: debian, redmine, rmagick

I have installed Redmine2.0 under Debian sucessfully.

I did type gem install RMagick and it work fine, then I restarted my webserver.

I still don't have Rmagick detected in Redmine, and I have no typical error, what to do ?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.4, Redmine use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to install and manage dependancies. So you don't need to install manually gems...

Did `bundle install` in your Redmine directory succeeded ?

> I still don't have Rmagick detected in Redmine

You mean in `Administration` > `Information` > `RMagick available (optional)` ?

I suggest you to try the above command and see if it succeeds...

Comment: I haev redmine 2.0, and yes I mean in Administration > Information > RMagick available (optional).
So I tried bundle install in my redmine fodler and it did suceed : Your bundle is complete, but in the list, I can't find RMagick, when I type bundle show RMagick I have "could not find gem 'RMagick'.

Comment: Beware of the case ! The gem is named `rmagick`. Have you installed ImageMagick on your system ?

Comment: Yes I did apt-get install libmagickwand-dev, is that it ?
I did too "gem install rmagick" and it says sucessfully installed rmagick-2.13.1, When I do bundle show in my redmine folder, I have a success but still no rmagick in the list of gem

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile` ? 
What's your ruby version ? rmagick-2 is for Ruby 1.9.x

Comment: I also met this problem. RMagick seems installed successfully.  I create a ruby file with require "RMagick", no error happens. RMagick is also in Bundle list. But in Redmine, it always tell me RMagic unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your RMagick load unsuitable imagemagick version. So

1. Open redmine/lib/redmine.rb file
2. you can see 
   begin
     require 'RMagick' unless Object.const_defined?(:Magick)
   rescue LoadError
3. Before this line, add 
   RMAGICK_BYPASS_VERSION_TEST = true
4. Save
5. Restart apache

Comment: I tried this solution with Debian 7 and Redmine 2.5.1, but sadly it doesn't work. I also installed librmagick-ruby ruby-rmagick and I have the gem rmagick 2.13.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed redmine via `apt-get`, you should install rmagick using `apt-get install ruby-rmagick`.